# Magento2 what scopes for observer exist?

Tags: magento2

I know I can have a `events.xml` directly in `etc`, in `etc/frontend` and `etc/adminhtml`. If I want to regsiter an observer for the event `sales_order_save_before` it does either work in `etc/frontend` nor in `etc/adminhtml`. Do I have to place it globally in `etc` or is there enother specific scope for REST calls?

Can I find a list of all existing scopes somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not test it yet but I have seen a specific webapi_rest scope in some video. Here is an example I found when searching for it:

https://github.com/javilumbrales/magento2-openshift/tree/master/public/app/code/Magento/CatalogRule/etc/webapi_rest

**===UPDATE===**

the available scopes for configuration files can also be found here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/required-configuration-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of existing configuration scopes in Magento:

```
 - <your module root dir>/etc/
 - <your module root dir>/etc/adminhtml/
 - <your module root dir>/etc/frontend/
 - <your module root dir>/etc/webapi_rest/
 - <your module root dir>/etc/webapi_soap/
 - <your module root dir>/etc/graphql/
 - <your module root dir>/etc/crontab/
```

You can check `Magento\Framework\App\AreaList` class and its `$areas` argument for area configuration list that is passed from `di.xml` files.